# Hit a service running on localhost from inside a docker image

Tags: docker

I'm on mac os, I have a service running on my machine on localhost:8000

now I want to launch a docker image and hit this service from here.

I did a docker bridge and I use it from inside, but it is not working. 
Here are my steps:

My host ip:

```
ifconfig

en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 98:01:a7:b0:2b:41
    inet 192.168.0.70 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

I hit my service from host:

```
curl localhost:8000  #this is working!
```

I create a bridge and I use it:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 dockernet
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/src" --network=dockernet  qatests /bin/bash
```

from inside docker, I do a curl but it is not working:

```
curl 192.168.0.1:8000 #it's not working :-(
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is the service running on localhost or all interfaces? What is the output of ss -tnl or netstat -tnl ?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is this [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/2127492)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I've discovered that if I ping my pc ip, I can see it even from the docker image. 
For convenience, I did a lounch script witch get my current IP and launch the docker image making my ip accessible under "mymac" address
So what i did is lunching

```
MY_IP=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}')

docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/src" --add-host=mymac:$MY_IP qatests 
/bin/bash
```

inside docker I can now lunch:

```
curl mymac:8000 #it works! now mymac is my pc outside docker
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to create a new network. You can use the default one (bridge).

Just check which ip is associated to the `docker0` interface in your host with `ip` or `ifconfig` (in my case is `172.17.42.1`), and use that ip from inside the container:

```
$ curl 172.17.42.1:8000
```